# How to detect automated translations?

Tags: перевод

I got a translation from a translator which I found online and feel like they might not know Russian at all and just used some of the services like Google translate. I wonder if there is some way to check for this?

For example, here's some of his text:

> Создавайте центры обработки данных с системами охлаждения и низким уровнем пыли. Снизьте уровень шума в исследовательских лабораториях.

> После вашего открытия пандемия вируса будет упоминаться только в учебниках истории.

> Максимальная сумма займа базируется на вашем кредитном рейтинге

> Из-за нестабильности местной валюты и высоких темпов инфляции ведущая сторона рассматривает возможность замены фиатной валюты цифровым публичным реестром. Главный оппонент – министр финансов, который говорит, что инфляция в долгосрочной перспективе полезна для экономики.

When I run it through Google translate it seems to be alright, but since it isn't exactly what the original English text was, it's hard to tell as I don't speak Russian.

Any ideas how to detect this? Thanks.

Comment: I would also appreciate if someone told me if the text above is valid Russian? so I know whether to keep working with this translator or not.

Comment: If we can't, the translator AI must have fulfilled the [Turing test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test). Such a short snippet (esp. of a simple technical text) wouldn't be enough to assess, though. This one is not ideal but generally valid, and not beyond the possibility a mediocre human translator would produce. The only formal problem with this text is that the two sentences are in slightly different tenses without an apparent justification.

Comment: @Zeus thanks. I have update the question with a couple more examples.

Comment: In English many of the verb forms are the same: "Ask him to run.", "Run for your life!", "They run in the mornings." In the first example the translator has resolved the ambiguity incorrectly and absurdly turning a list of project goals into a list of commands. The result reads something like this: "Go ye and create data processing centers with cooling systems and a low dust level! Reduce the noise level in the research laboratories!". All three examples are woodenly literal and tiring to read.

Comment: Look, isolated sentences don't make a justice. It is a longer coherent text that is more difficult to translate well for AI. The two new sentences do have some traits of machine translation, but again, not beyond a mediocre human. Instead of giveaway machine errors, they feel like English [calques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque) - but this is not uncommon for a technical text. The most obvious sign is that after "После вашего открытия" there _must_ be a comma, yet modern English doesn't use a comma here. Machine translation doesn't bother much with correct punctuation (yet).

Comment: P.S. I'm not answering the question because there _may_ be tools available to detect machine translations generally (for non-speakers). But I'm not aware of them.

Comment: @David42, this may be justified if it is a list of recommendations to achieve some goal.

Comment: @Zeus In my experience formal recommendations are expressed using verbs in the infinitive. The imperative is general reserved for cases where immediate compliance is expected such as in the instructions for filling out a form.

Comment: @David42, [not at all necessarily](https://www.mskcc.org/ru/cancer-care/patient-education/managing-covid-19-home) (just a random list of recommendations).

Comment: I found a longer sentence which can be cumbersome for a machine to grasp. Maybe this one will show clearly?

Comment: @Zeus, why do you think there should be a comma after "После вашего открытия"? Isn't that just a plain non participle-based adverbial of time, same as "завтра", "скоро" or "через пять минут"?

Comment: This is not a question about Russian language - it's a question about detecting translation - therefore, classifying text as "natural" or "translated". Apart from that this question is too wide to answer in general.

Comment: Deepl.com has been so good recently I often cannot distinguish its translation from how I'd do that on my own, i.e. it's near perfect. It struggles with certain English words which have numerous different subtle meanings (it often picks the wrong Russian word) but other than that it's just great and miles better than any other AI translation service. BTW, those translation errors could have easily be done by inexperienced translators or English learners.